# Why when using .wrap() in jQuery, do I seem to lose my float css property?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery and I have code like the following:

```
var myElem = $("#childDiv");
console.log(myElem.css('float')); // = left, as defined in the CSS
myElem.wrap('<div class="container"></div>');
console.log(myElem.css('float')); // = none, Why?
```

It is so simple, but after that wrap I seem to lose my float property, am I making a small mistake somewhere?

Comment: Probably after wrapping the element the CSS selector doesn't match the element.

Comment: It is working fine in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3jsoab1/ Can you post the full HTML/CSS code, so that we can have closer look at it.